# Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both ... libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I upgraded to the latest **Java 7u40** on **MacOS X** and started getting the following message on the console when launching my application using Eclipse. The app works fine but I would like to find out the cause of the problem and hopefully a fix for it.

```
objc[10012]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Does anyone know why this message is printed and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like this is also covered in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic), which suggests reverting to u25.

Comment: While this might be a viable option to remedy this specific kind of problem - this might make you vulnerable to security leaks fixed in u45 and beyond.

Comment: The same thing is happening with jdk1.8.0_05

Comment: A year has passed and the bug is still nagging every Java developer that happens to use a Mac (verified with jdk1.7.0_67 on OS X 10.9.3). Shameful. Can anybody with the appropriate login please reopen these bugs http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8021205 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025876

Comment: Bug still exists for jdk1.8.0_25. Is this just a nagging message or an actual problem?

Comment: Problem still exists in jdk1.8.0_60 with a slight difference: objc[3457] instead. From my experience in the past year since I last comment, it's did not affect runtime, so I am brushing it off as an annoying message.

Comment: A [bug report of this issue](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022291) suggests a fix may be included with the JDK9 release. The same bug report says this: "For those who keep asking about this: The message is benign, there is no negative impact from this problem since both copies of that class are identical (compiled from the exact same source). It is purely a cosmetic issue."

Comment: All these answers are insufficient because they aren't written in the context of someone using JEnv shims.

Answer (score 180):

⚠️ **For JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA**: Go to  `Help -> Edit Custom Properties...`. Create the file if it asks you to create it. To disable the error message paste the following to the file you created:

```
idea_rt
idea.no.launcher=true
```

This will take effect on the restart of the IntelliJ.

Comment: The OP was using Eclipse, not IntelliJ. So you're giving them instructions for modifying settings in the wrong editor (hence it not being marked as correct).

Comment: I agree with @Allison - if this answer included a means for Eclipse it would be excellent. But answering for the wrong IDE?

Answer (score 120):

As of October 2017, this issue is now **resolved** in

- [jdk1.9](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022291)
- [jdk1.8.152](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8170041)
- [jdk1.7.161](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8170440)

Comment: I just installed java version "1.8.0_144", and I faced the issue.

Comment: @Reihan_amn you will, until build 152

Comment: I had issues with jdk1.8.65 but jdk1.8.152 fixed this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

1. Install Java 7u21 from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u21-oth-JPR
2. Set these variables:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Run your app and have fun :)

Comment: Works also for 1.8.0_92:

# in .zshrc or .bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: @Lichtamberg thanks this fixed my issues on Java 8 mac osx. I have added your comment as an answer as almost all other answers work but are now absolute.

Comment: @gotoalberto How will this environment variable solve the issue when both the implementation of the JavaLaunchHelper resides in the Home directory?

Comment: @Lichtamberg I'm using sonar runner to start evaluating code coverage of my app. I'm still getting the same issue with the version you have mentioned above. though I've tried many 8 version with its patches in my mac os. No Luck.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. Java 7u21 (besides being released in 2013 and thus having missed out on four years of patches big and small) has a arbitrary code execution vulnerability: https://gist.github.com/frohoff/24af7913611f8406eaf3

Comment: If you installed java via the official .dmg then it should have created a symlink at `/Library/Java/Home` which will point to the correct `JAVA_HOME`, therefore a cleaner approach would be adding to your `~/.bash_profile` something like `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home`. Then after upgrading java you won't need to update your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 11):

Copy Pasting @Lichtamberg's comments to gotoalberto's answer

**Works also for Java 1.8:**

```
# in ~/.zshrc and ~/.bashrc

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This fixed my issue on java 8.

Comment: Still experiencing the problem in Android Studio (2.2p3) after editing ~/.zshrc and ~/.bashrc

Comment: doesnt work for intellij, is there a next step after create / edit these files?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but I got this issue only after installing **JVM Monitor**.

Uninstalling JVM Monitor solved the issue for me.

Comment: Same here, JVM Monitor for Eclipse was causing the message (JBoss 7.1, JDK 1.8.0.X).

Comment: It started for me when I installed eclEmma plugin in eclipse

Comment: Same problem here. Uninstalled JVM monitor and this no longer shows up

Answer (score 4):

As other answers detail, this is a bug in the JDK (up to u45) which will be fixed in JDK7u60 - while this is not out yet, you may download the b01 from: https://jdk7.java.net/download.html

It's beta, but fixed that issue for me.

Comment: I installed u60 but still get Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: looks like it was re-introduced between b01 and b02

Comment: Any reference to the bug? URL ?

Comment: Its actually not fixed still.  They backed the fix out of u60

Answer (score 3):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-stackoverflow/QZGJg2tlfA4

From what I've found online, this is **a bug** introduced in JDK 1.7.0_45. I've read it will be fixed in the next release of Java, but it's not out yet. Supposedly, it was fixed in 1.7.0_60b01, but I can't find where to download it and 1.7.0_60b02 re-introduces the bug.

I managed to get around the problem by reverting back to JDK 1.7.0_25. Probably not the solution you wanted, but it's the only way I've been able to get it working. Don't forget add JDK 1.7.0_25 in Eclipse after installing the JDK.

Please DO NOT REPLY directly to this email but go to StackOverflow:
[Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic/20807657#20807657)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, I downgraded to [JDK version 1.7.0_21](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html). then I used [this](http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/) little bash script to change the version I use.

```
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
   removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
   fi
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
 }

 function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
 }
```

Once you have the bash script in your zshrc/bshrc file, just call `setJdk 1.7.0_21` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some struggling, what worked for me was completely removing the current JDK, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23092014/213210):

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchAgents/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.oracle.java.JavaUpdateHelper
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.java.JavaUpdateHelper.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/Preferences/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
```

Then installed 1.7.0_21, which was downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u21-oth-JPR).

Now `java -version` prompts:

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

### July 2019

OSX Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132)
IntelliJ 2019-1 Community Edition. It worked setting idea.properties file. I also configured JAVA_HOME pointing to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/

#### custom IntelliJ IDEA properties

idea_rt
idea.no.launcher=true

Answer (score -1):

If you're using IntelliJ & Mac just go to Project structure -> SDK and make sure that there is Java listed but it points to sth like

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Rather than user home...

Answer (score -3):

jdk-7u80-macosx-x64.dmg fix this problem.