# Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Have a simple Google App Engine Web Application Project on Eclipse Kepler on Mac OS X with java version "1.7.0_45"

Running into the following  :

```
objc[5398]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

when I try to run as web application on localhost

Possibly related to the following issue :

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10046

Any help would be useful.

Comment: So how did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: The same thing is happening with jdk1.8.0_05

Comment: If you close something as a duplicate put the link to the duplicate, or reopen it!

Comment: See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43182301/3696510 for when the issue will be resolved.

Comment: @Pinocchio : Haven't solved it but it doesn't block me since it is just a warning and the app runs anway. I added JAVA_HOME to PATH as described in the link above but that doesn't fix the warning either.

Answer (score 51):

From what I've found online, this is a bug introduced in JDK 1.7.0_45. It appears to also be present in JDK 1.7.0_60. A [bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022291) on Oracle's website states that, while there was a fix, it was removed before the JDK was released. I do not know why the fix was removed, but it confirms what we've already suspected -- the JDK is still broken.

The bug report claims that the error is benign and should not cause any run-time problems, though one of the comments disagrees with that. In my own experience, I have been able to work without any problems using JDK 1.7.0_60 despite seeing the message.

If this issue is causing serious problems, here are a few things I would suggest:

- Revert back to [JDK 1.7.0_25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u25-oth-JPR) until a fix is added to the JDK.
- Keep an eye on the [bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022291) so that you are aware of any work being done on this issue. Maybe even add your own comment so Oracle is aware of the severity of the issue.
- Try the [JDK early releases](https://jdk7.java.net/download.html) as they come out. One of them might fix your problem.

Instructions for installing the JDK on Mac OS X are available at [JDK 7 Installation for Mac OS X](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html). It also contains instructions for removing the JDK.

Comment: Reverting to u25 worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have JDK 1.7.0_45 ; Everything was working until I updated the latest eclipse plugin version. Able to start the devserver on old project(the project that has been created before plugin update). But not able to start the dev-server on new project(The project that has been created after update). Will changing any project specific configuration will help?

Comment: @Raj Hi Raj. You might try deleting the launch configuration for the project and creating a new one. You might also try posting this as a new Stack Overflow question with the exact error message.

Comment: Just downloaded [JDK 7u51](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html) for the Mac, and the problem is still there.

Comment: reverting to u25 solved it for me too. that was nasty!! thanx a lot

Comment: Get the latest u60 here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html

Comment: I am still seeing the error on u60, but it didn't stop me from launching a web project in Eclipse. So it seems like you can do development on u60 despite the error.

Comment: you said it was going to be fixed on the next release of Java, how do I figure out if it has been fixed yet?

Comment: @Das How do you revert to u25?

Comment: 1.7.0_60b07 still fails for me on Mac OS 10.9.2

Comment: @Pinocchio I've updated the answer to include newer information found on the Internet. I've added a link to the bug report pertaining to this issue, some suggestions for working around the issue, and a link to instructions for installing/uninstalling the JDK on OS X.

Comment: Verified bug still exists in JDK 1.8.0 on Mac OS 10.9.2. Running into it trying to run jacoco code coverage in Maven on Java 8. The PATH fix mentioned below does not seem to help.

Comment: Recommending to revert to an older JDK is a bit irresponsible. There were many security bugs that were fixed since that version.

Comment: The problem is there on jdk1.7.0_79

Comment: Bug still exists in JDK 1.8.0_72 on Mac OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan).

Comment: Bug is also still in JDK 1.7.0_79 on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

Comment: "soon to be fixed" bug still exists in JDK 1.8.0_92 on Max OSX 10.11 (El Capitan).  <JimmyValmer> I mean, come on. </JimmyValmer>

Comment: Still exists in JDK 1.8.0_92 on macOS 10.12 (Sierra)

Comment: Still facing this issue with JAVA_1.8.0_101

Comment: Bug still exists in java version 1.8.0_121, 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13),

Comment: See answer from gotoalberto below. Defining a JAVA_HOME environment variable and add it to your system path should get ride of this warning message JavaLaunchHelper. It is generally a preferred practice to have a JAVA_HOME environment variable defined.

Comment: *apparently* will be fixed in 8u152 and Java 9:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8170041

Comment: Bug still exists in java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17) on macOs Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)

Comment: Still an issue on : java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Still an issue on macOS High Sierra: `java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 7):

1. Install Java 7u21 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u21-oth-JPR
2. set these variables:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home"
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Run your app and fun :)

(Minor update: put variable value in quote)

Comment: Works also for 1.8.0_92:

# in ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. Java 7u21 (besides being released in 2013 and thus having missed out on four years of patches big and small) has a arbitrary code execution vulnerability: https://gist.github.com/frohoff/24af7913611f8406eaf3