# Problems with updating cassandra database and java problems

Tags: java, cassandra

I was trying to upgrade my `cassandra 1.2.13` to `cassandra 2.0.5` but I was having some issues. I was follwing the instructions here:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/NEWS.txt

it says:

```
    2.0.5
    =====
...
    Upgrading
    ---------
        - If your cluster began on a version before 1.2, check that your secondary
          index SSTables are on version 'ic' before upgrading.  If not, run
          'nodetool upgradesstables' if on 1.2.14 or later, or run 'nodetool
          upgradesstables ks cf' with the keyspace and secondary index named
          explicitly otherwise...
```

So since I have not initialized anything (any tables/kspaces and stuff) that matters I did:

```
nodetool upgradesstables
```

However when I do that command the following error is thrown at me:

```
objc[88756]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I tried googling that error but was still unsure how to proceed. Does someone know how to fix this without screwing up java environment?

I have a MAC OS X 10.9.1

Answer (score 1):

it's a bug in JDK 1.7.0_45. you must upgrade your jdk.

see also [Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic)

Comment: how do you upgrade your jdk?

Comment: I installed the new one _51 and I still had the same problem. How do I uninstall this or what do u recommend to do? I don't understand the answer/link u posted.