# Java 8: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both

Tags: java, cassandra, java-8

I'm trying to launch Cassandra and I'm running into an issue with JavaLaunchHelper being located in two places. I'm running Java 8. Here's the exact error:

```
objc[413]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Found a similar question for Java 7:

[Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic)

What's the best way to go about solving this?

Answer (score 16):

This is a bug in the JDK and is still not fixed (as of 8u25). See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18958973/97149).

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal Simply believe that both versions of the code are kept the same by oracle and ignore the message.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem, just an annoying message.  But Cassandra hasn't been verified against java 8 yet, so you may see some strangeness.

Comment: You are right that it isn't a problem, but this is not an answer... It also most definitely is not a Cassandra problem.

Comment: @DCKing I'll select a better answer if someone offers one up.

Answer (score 1):

You must go to Preferences/Build, Execution, Deployment/Debugger and disable the option: "Force Classic VM for JDK 1.3.x and earlier" This works for me

Comment: maybe it was a coincidence on your side, because it has no effect on me

Answer (score 0):

put lines to files ~/.bashrc (or/and ~/.zshrc) and save

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and then restart (logout/login) terminal (IDE)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Both are set and the warning still occurs with 1.8.0_111 in both zsh and bash.

Comment: I'm running jdk1.8.0_102 and I still get the error even after trying this solution as well

Comment: @MichaelF Check if you're using java version you want with terminal command "java -version"

Comment: @Andrey Yes, it is running the right version.  I just continually get this now, even if I am running with your fixes to the bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Two steps fix this problem:

1.Navigate to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` and remove the `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` directory.

2.Navigate to `/Library/PreferencePanes` and remove `JavaControlPanel.prefpane`.

Essentially, do one thing: uninstall jre !