# Android Proguard - Build fails with proguard-android-optimize.txt

Tags: android, proguard, android-multidex

I am trying to build a project with proguard enabled. It works fine if i use "proguard-android.txt" as the default rules file but fails with proguard-android-optimize.txt" which is understandable but i just dont understand the error that i am getting :

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        /Users/sayed/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx -JXmx4g --dex --no-optimize 
--multi-dex --main-dex-list /Users/sayed/workspace/git/myproject/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/maindexlist.txt --multi-dex --output /Users/sayed/workspace/git/myproject/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/sayed/workspace/git/myproject/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
      Error Code:
        1
      Output:
```

and then there is a long description which exceeds the SO limit for body characters.

Here is my gradle file-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 54
        versionName "2.002"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
        resConfigs "en", "fr" , "ar"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    repositories{
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
        compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
        compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
        compile project(':Adjust')
        compile project(':aFileChooser-cbccac1d1cb74a6d57d25c5ded61e4bf4fc40c91')
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile (group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.0.0.1'){
            //    exclude group:'picasso'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:4.+'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.2'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'


        /*compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2') {
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude module: 'httpcore'
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
        }
        compile ('oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2') {
            exclude module: 'commons-codec'
        }*/

        androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
        androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
        androidTestCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19')

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
}
```

and here is the proguard-rules.pro file -

```
-libraryjars libs

# We only want obfuscation
#-keepattributes InnerClasses,Signature

# Sdk
-keep public interface com.zendesk.sdk.** { *; }
-keep public class com.zendesk.sdk.** { *; }

# Gson
-keep interface com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }


# Retrofit
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# NewRelic
-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses

# Jackson
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
 public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class mypackage.parsers.KombiJacksonParser.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
}

#Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

# apache
-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
```

**Edit -** relavant section of error. The rest of the description is warnings

```
objc[17014]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

and then this in the end -

```
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
    expected type int but found com.c.fd
    ...at bytecode offset 000000a8
    locals[0000]: <addr:002a>
    locals[0001]: I
    ...while working on block 00a8
    ...while working on method <clinit>:()V
    ...while processing <clinit> ()V
    ...while processing com/c/fd.class
    1 error; aborting
```

Comment: From Your description above, I guess You are working with Android Studio, right? can You post Your gradle file?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant part of the error output too? Is it correct to have `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-android-optimize.txt`?

Comment: try to add "compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.+" to Your gradle file...

Comment: Yeah thats fine. I am just testing it for debug build type for now. android studios has these 2 default templates for proguard that you can use.

Comment: I added the suggested library to build file but didn't work.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i added the relevant sections from error output. The warnings are mostly related to zendesk mobile sdk

Comment: I think there could be a problem with Your multiDex configuration. Read this API Guide and follow the instructions:  http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I dont think its a problem with that because it works fine without proguard and even with the proguard-android.txt. It only fails when i use the optimised version

Comment: @sayed for the JDK error, have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic) question? Have you tried with JDK8?

Comment: @Sufian Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try reverting back to an older version and update you

Comment: @Sufian by changing the java version i got rid of the Java exception but the rest of the exceptions are the same. I managed to get the stacktrace but even that doesn't make sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661488/android-gradle-apk-generation-fails-with-proguard