# mobile first platform server wont start

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I built a MFP project with the MFP CLI

I ran mfp stop to stop my server

now when i run mfp start, mfp run, mfp restart, the server wont start

here are my cli logs

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp stop**

objc[84655]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Stopping server worklight.
Server worklight is not running.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp start**

Initializing MobileFirst Console.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp deploy**

Initializing MobileFirst Console.
Error: The MobileFirst server that you have configured does not appear to be running. Start the server with 'mobilefirst start'.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp start**

Initializing MobileFirst Console.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp status**

objc[84719]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Server worklight is not running.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp run**

Initializing MobileFirst Console.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp status**

objc[84756]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Server worklight is not running.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp restart**

Initializing MobileFirst Console.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp status**

objc[84790]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Server worklight is not running.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp start**

Initializing MobileFirst Console.

**macsupports-MacBook-Pro-2:yoMAUI hannade$ mfp status**

objc[84882]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Server worklight is not running.

Comment: Derek, I think it would help if you can format your log properly, please. It's almost unreadable at the moment.

Comment: I've bolded the commands i ran, and below the command is the output

Comment: Which MobileFirst Platform version and what is its full build number?

Comment: found this when i ran mfp -v  7.0.0.00.20150312-0738

Comment: Use "mfp -v" to print the full version number.

Comment: found this when i ran mfp -v 7.0.0.00.20150312-0738

Answer (score 2):

Try

> mfp -d start

or

> mfp -dd start

I got a different startup problem and I have no clues what happened because the prompt returned normally.
Until I run mfp -d start to find out tools.jar is not in the classpath. Therefore, I updated %JAVA_HOME% and %PATH% variables and this resolved my problem.

You may also want to check logs with

> mfp logs

---

Update #1
Per your comment, it seems that the JVM somehow failed to start with exit code = 1.
I would check that area first. For example, a simple search hits similar issues not specific to MFP and seems to point to a defect in JDK on Mac OS X.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20807657/2821355

Hope this helps

Comment: when i check the logs i see this: 6/5/15 11:36:58.465 AM java[45416]: objc[45416]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Here is my status.log file 
arg0=worklight
arg1=--pid=
arg2=--status
exit=1

Comment: Java home:  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
              Install root:  /Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150430-1556/server/wlp/
          System libraries:  /Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150430-1556/server/wlp/lib/
                 User root:  /Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150430-1556/server/wlp/usr/
             Server config:  /Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150430-1556/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/

Comment: Server output:  /Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150430-1556/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Download the latest CLI iFix relese from IBM Fix Central (June 6th 2015 and above) as it contains fixes (That at least for me) allow for the server to properlly start.

Uninstall the current CLI installation
Download the latest CLI from IBM Fix Central website 
Install new version and try again

---

Are you also using MobileFirst Studio? You might have a server process still running.

Try this, from Terminal:

1. `lsof -i :10080`
2. If you get a list of process, then
3. `kill -9 number-of-process`

Comment: when i run lsof -i :10080 i get nothing

Comment: This is happening on more than one mac, the cli wont start a server, says it's initializing console, never starts the server

Comment: Even if the port is not being held, there could be an errant Java process out there.  Try running:

pgrep -f "wlp.*worklight"

run a "kill" on the process, if its still there, run "kill -9"

Comment: There is an active defect (2 actually) trying to be resolved for this issue with Liberty server.  Its my belief that Liberty gets confused when IP addresses change.  Other times I've seen this is when using two different version of MFP (or CLI, then Studio, etc).

Comment: so what should i do, i still cant get it to start

Comment: I'd like you to download the latest available version of the CLI (from May 2015, you're using a version from March 2015) to see if there is any difference. Where from did you download the CLI version you're using?

Comment: As a customer or IBM business partner you can download it from the IBM Fix Central website: http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other+software/IBM+MobileFirst+Platform+Foundation&release=7.0.0.0&platform=Mac+OSX&function=fixId&fixids=7.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201505211954&includeRequisites=0&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http

Comment: i got the latest version of the cli, now i have version 7.0.0.00.20150430-1604
  mfp start still wont start the server

Comment: mfp build doesn't seem to work with this version of the cli either now

Comment: Yeah, I'm experiencing issues even with newer builds than 20150430... I've pinged the CLI team. This needs to be resolved(!).

Comment: None. The team is still looking into it, it works for some doesn't work for others... Feel free to open a PMR to receive support.

Comment: Try rebooting and cleaning your ibm tmp for liberty server. rm -rf ~/.ibm    also try reversing the arguments with "-d" at the end do $mfp start -d . can you try with a brand new project $mfp create and then do $mfp start

Comment: Carlos these issues have disappeared with the June 8th iFix of the CLI.