# Jdk1.7.0_79.jdk and AppEngine: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I have a simple Google App Engine project. When I try to run as web application on localhost I get this:

```
objc[49307]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <app directory>
```

**Config:** MAC OSX El Capitan + Eclipse 4.4.2 + Google Plugin for Ecplise 4.4

I thought that bug was already fixed by Oracle with same problem on version 1.7.0_45:

- [Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic)
- [objc[10012]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both ... libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794573/objc10012-class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-libinstrument-dyl))

So I can't test locally my app with Google Plugin For Eclipse.. What's wrong ?

Comment: Strange as this should only be a warning message. Did you find a solution or is this still happening with the latest App Engine SDK?

Comment: For the moment nope... I'll push every commit to appengine.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are still receiving this error preventing you from running your application on localhost. Is this correct? If so, what version of the App Engine SDK are you using currently for this deployment?