# Upgrading to com.android.tools.build:gradle 2.0 causes JavaLaunchHelper conflict during compilation

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I upgraded my project Android Studio 2.0 (which triggered me to upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.50 to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0), I get the following error:

```
Error:objc[17636]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

The error seems to be benign and I tried some of the suggestions at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204797 and it did not seem to help.

I've also seen numerous reports of this being a JDK issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic) (which has not fixed yet), but it's odd that this only happens after I upgraded the gradle version.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidating Cache and restarting android studio worked for me. I was on AS canary 3.0 and my Gradle upgrade was from 3.3 to 3.5

update: This is only a temporary fix, the problem seems to come back after some runs