# Bootrun error when trying to run grails

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I was setting up to run graddle from my terminal using "grails dev run-app" command, then an error occurred.

I'm not sure what causing the error, but what I have installed are:

- Java JDK 1.8.0_111
- Grails 3.0.14
- MySQL

I have tried to use "grails clean" and try to use "export=JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home'" but still outputs the same error.

**This is the simplified long error:**

Running application...
objc[3493]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'mobileeyeclinic'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

  > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  | Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Deeply thanks for anyone who could provide a solution to this matter.

Comment: @YuJiaao you should put this as answer, so i can upvote you. Thank you very much btw, it seems that I got the wrong password for mysql localhost.

Comment: Your problem may like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352512/grails-3-x-failure-bootrun/44269349#44269349). You can follow my answer described their.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message `Running application... Which one is undefined` is not matter. I think your failure cause by wrong password for `'mobileeyeclinic'@'localhost'` or may be the MySQL is not running as a service. See this link [Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic) for more info

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create
>   initial connections of pool.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'mobileeyeclinic'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

You have no rights to access to the bbdd you have set on the application.yml file.