# Grails 3.x Failure bootRun

Tags: java, grails, gradle

I'm trying to run a project in grails 3.1.11 but i've a error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.10"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "sias"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Anyone to help me?? Thanks.

Comment: You need to kill the old server instance or whatever service is listening on port 8080. Kill your active java processes and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced such problem in `GRAILS 3.x` version. You can overcome this problem by following these procedures.

**Step 1**

Stop your application by `stop-app`  command in cmd or replace `run-app` command by `stop-app`  command through 'edit configuration' window

**Step 2**

Then change the GRAILS default http '8080' port to any customs port, like '8090'. For changing default port you should go

> grails-app[main]--> conf-->application.yml

In `application.yml` file you just keep this under all the code of this file.

```
server:
  port: 8090
```

**Step 3**

Then run your application by `run-app` command replacing `stop-app` command through 'edit configuration' window or cmd

Here, `stop-app` command is needed because application cached the previous command with default environment. When you change something then it doesn't make any sense in application. So, by "stop-app" command it kills all previous process, erases cached.