# Class JavaLaunchHelper error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

Getting this error while creating build in Android Studio 2.2.3. Earlier it was working fine, recently facing this issue. Please help some one to resolve this issue.

Java Version : 1.8.0_101.

> Error:objc[10662]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x103a1d4c0) and
>   /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib
>   (0x103ae14e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: can you post complete log ?

Comment: may be this can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794751/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-whic

Comment: @SurabhiSingh already posted complete log.