# Java JAR-file could not be launched, Mac

Tags: java, macos

I'm simply trying to open a JAR file on my Mac running 10.9.5.
But can't seem to get it open. I have tried litteraly everything, but I have this error code from console:

Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/./libjli.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

One guy said that there are conflict between two files. I just want to open it, have not made anything. Developer wont get back to me.

Can some on you guys check out the jar file?

Thanks in advance! Need help :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [objc\[10012\]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both ... libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794573/objc10012-class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-libinstrument-dyl)

Answer (score 0):

OK i had the same problem weeks ago.

Open terminale and check your default java version. 
`java -version`
after this check your java path

`which java`

if you want to run your program with your java installation edit your `PATH`variable.

```
PATH=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java:$PATH
export $PATH
```

then you can run your program for terminal

```
java -jar ....
```

Comment: which java gives me: /usr/bin/java 
So I replace path with that:
-bash: /usr/bin/java/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java:$/usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

:(

Comment: Ok is /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java a file or a directory. In the Path you can only save directories. And where is is $/usr/bin/java from. normally you don't have '$' in a shell variable.

Comment: It is a file. When I'm in the bin folder I have this java file, so with ..../bin/java it's a file.
At the end of both of your lines its a $, ain't I suppose to add those?
I see there is PATH both at the end and front of the first line, I do add /usr/bin/java there right? But then I get:
- bash: /usr/bin/java/Library/Internet: Not a directory
:/