# JUL TO SLF4J on TomEE 1.7.2 with maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j, apache-tomee

I would like to use SLF4J api with LOG4J2 impl inside a tomee maven project. As a result I added inside my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I edited the logging.properties file of TomEE like this :

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

And I try to run my project with this maven command :

```
mvn package tomee:run
```

Unfortunately I got an exception :

```
objc[2756]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Handler error
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:560)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:503)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:311)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:93)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:59)
```

I tried to add dependencies as lib :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <context>ROOT</context>
                <libs>
                    <li>org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12</li>
                    <lib>org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.12</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I can see inside maven console :

```
[INFO] Copied 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12' in '/Users/xxx/Work/Git/xxx/target/apache-tomee/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
[INFO] Copied 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.12' in '/Users/xxx/Work/Git/xxx/target/apache-tomee/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
```

But I got same exception :(

After a look inside the jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar I can see that the org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler class file is present.

I don't understand why tomee can't find it ? Does it possible the mac's JDK bug has something related with this ? [objc[10012]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both ... libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794573/objc10012-class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-libinstrument-dyl)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12</li>
```

b is missing inside the li tag. Just updated with lib