# PowerMockito (with Mockito) failing with ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

We are using Powermockito with Mockito to mock some static classes. There seems to be `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` thrown every time.

Can you help me identify where the problem is?

**Java class under test**

```
package com.myproject.myproduct.search.domain;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.MultiMatchQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;

public class MyQueryBuilder {

    public MultiMatchQueryBuilder getMultiMatchQueryBuilder() {
        MultiMatchQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("term", "field1");
        builder.field("field1",200.9f);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

**Junit test with Powermock runner**

```
package com.myproject.myproduct.search.domain;

import org.elasticsearch.index.query.MultiMatchQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(QueryBuilders.class)
public class MyQueryBuilderTest {

    private MyQueryBuilder myQueryBuilder;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(QueryBuilders.class);
        MultiMatchQueryBuilder builder = PowerMockito.mock(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.class);
    }
}
```

That's it. The test code does not work  as soon as I try to mock
MultiMatchQueryBuilder.

**This is the Exception:**

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.logging.DeprecationLogger.(DeprecationLogger.java:138)
>     at org.elasticsearch.common.ParseField.(ParseField.java:35)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:53)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
>     at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)
>     at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)
>     at
>   com.spartasystems.stratas.search.domain.MyQueryBuilderTest.testBoostSetProperly(MyQueryBuilderTest.java:22)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)  at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.elasticsearch.Build.(Build.java:47)   ... 41 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

**Note:**

*The source code of actual underlying elasticsearch classes can be found here*

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.java

and

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/MultiMatchQueryBuilder.java

Comment: @Michael That's just example code. The presence or absence of "term" does not make a difference here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both ... libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794573/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-libinstrument-dylib-one-of-th)

Comment: @Michael Point taken. Thank you

Comment: @user7294900 No, its not. That's a line of output that does not affect applications at run-time. Worth sorting out, but not related to the exception.

Comment: Try adding this @PrepareForTest({MultiMatchQueryBuilder.class, QueryBuilders.class})and see.

Comment: `@PowerMockIgnore("org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*")` on the test class could probably help

Comment: What versions of elasticsearch, mockito and powermock do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling with mocks [`org.elasticsearch.Build#getElasticsearchCodebase`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/c19044ddf6a8ed421d75fdb3db6bb02b06350b8f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/Build.java#L81-L83)

```
Build.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

returns `null` because the code has no location (Dynamic method generated by cglib.)

So when [initializing `org.elasticsearch.Build`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/c19044ddf6a8ed421d75fdb3db6bb02b06350b8f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/Build.java#L41-L48) during your mock code using

```
final URL url = getElasticsearchCodebase(); // url is null
final String urlStr = url.toString(); // null pointer exception.
```

Of course, the mock will not success and throw `ExceptionInInitializerError` which indicates an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

---

You can easily reproduce this exception using following code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({QueryBuilders.class})
public class MyQueryBuilderTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Build current = Build.CURRENT;
    }

}
```