# Application exits with out any error

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I run Spring Boot Application it just shows

> objc[2039]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   (0x108aea4c0) and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib
>   (0x109b544e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

It was working well I had added unit test related dependencies and removed them after that it has got screwed up.

Here is my POM file

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j.version>2.2</log4j.version>
        <mariadb.version>1.1.7</mariadb.version>
        <swagger.version>2.0.1</swagger.version>
        <aws.ses.version>1.11.16</aws.ses.version>
        <aws.s3.version>1.11.16</aws.s3.version>
        <bcrypt.version>0.3m</bcrypt.version>
        <json.verion>0.6.0</json.verion>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.ses.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.s3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${mariadb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>${bcrypt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Did you try to `clean` after removing the dependencies?

Comment: I ran "mvn dependency:purge-local-repository" and "mvn clean" It is not working ., anything else I should do? Im using intellij

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both ... libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794573/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-libinstrument-dylib-one-of-th)

Comment: How are you running your application?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Running application from IntelliJ itself

Comment: I just cloned the application from my repository still I get the same issue however other projects are working without any issues. Is there any way to remove all dependency of this application from my machine and start fresh?